# difference array.any() vs. np.any(array())

Tags: numpy, any

Simple question, confusing output:
np.array([-1, 0, 1]).any() < 0
out: False   (why??)
but:
np.any(np.array([-1, 0, 1]))
out: True    (as expected)

Acoording to documentation both commands should be equivalent, but they aren't.

Comment: np.any and np.ndarray.any do the same thing, your example just has `< 0` for one of them, but not the other

Comment: what is `True<0`? Or did you mean to apply the `<` to the array first  `(np.array([-1, 0, 1])< 0`

Answer (score 2):

Numpy is used to provide a method and a function that do the exact same thing.

```
assert my_array.any() == numpy.any(my_array)
```

Here my_array.any() is the method and numpy.any(my_array) is the function.

It both return a Boolean. Here you ask why `np.array([-1, 0, 1]).any() < 0` returns `False` because `np.array([-1, 0, 1]).any()` is `True` which is equal to the value `1` and you ask if it is `< 0` which is `False`.

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
assert my_array.any() == True
assert my_array.any() == 1
assert my_array.any() > 0
assert np.any(my_array) == True
assert my_array.any() == np.any(my_array)
```